# ASP NET MVC CORE 2.2 - ViewComponent's Invoke() oddly genarates an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am develeping an online store where I've got a ViewComponent that is used to render a shopping cart html in the website's navigation bar.

I render the view component in the shared _Layout.cshtml by doing this:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("NavbarShoppingCart")
```

It used to work fine under MVC CORE 2.0 but since I upgraded to 2.2 the same code throws an InvalidOperationException:

> InvalidOperationException: Method 'Invoke' of view component
>   'ProjectName.Web.Views.Shared.NavbarShoppingCartViewComponent ' cannot
>   return a Task.

Here is the ViewComponent class:

```
public class NavbarShoppingCartViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IShoppingCartManager shoppingCartManager;

        public NavbarShoppingCartViewComponent(IShoppingCartManager shoppingCartManager)
        {
            this.shoppingCartManager = shoppingCartManager;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var shoppingCartId = this.HttpContext.Session.GetShoppingCartId();
            var items = this.shoppingCartManager.GetCartItems(shoppingCartId);

            return View("NavbarShoppingCart", items.Count());
        }
    }
```

The Invoke() method clearly returns a View, not a Task. I don't get it why this throws an error now. Any ideas?

Comment: If you've literally changed nothing other than the target dotnet version, you *may* have better luck posting on the aspnet core github issues page

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with your code in .net core 2.2, it works correctly.